# Writing (overriding) same XML file that I read

Tags: java, xml

I made a method to read XML files, but now I need to write or override that same XML file with the same tags, nodes and objects, but with different data inside child nodes.

First I want to make read and write working and then I have some ideas to maybe put the whole XML file into a buffer. Then I could put the whole XML under one class and just write that class again into the same XML this is just an idea, any suggestion or idea is welcome.

My XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Document Root -->
<DATA>
    <Settings USERNAME="test" PASSWORD="test" STATUS="active" / >
</DATA>
```

This is my code for reading:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Read {

    private final static String SETTINGS_LINE = Settings;

    public void readXML() {

        try {

            File xmlFile = new File("Test.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory documentFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

            // Normalize the XML file
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();

            for(int temp = 0; temp < nodeList.getLength(); temp++) {

                Node node = nodeList.item(temp);

                if(node instanceof Element && node.getNodeName() == SETTINGS_LINE) {

                    Element settings = (Element) node;

                    System.out.println("User" +settings.getAttribute("USERNAME"));
                    System.out.println("Password" +settings.getAttribute("PASSWORD"));
                    System.out.println("Status" +settings.getAttribute("STATUS"));


        }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

And this is the code for writing that is not working:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Modify {

    private final static String SETTINGS_LINE = "Settings";

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

       try {
        String filepath = "test.xml";
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();


        // Normalize the XML File
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();  

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();  

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

          Node node = nodeList.item(i);

              if (node instanceof Element && node.getNodeName() == SETTINGS_LINE) {  

                 Element settings = (Element) node;  

                 if("USERNAME".equals(node.getChildNodes())){
                     node.setTextContent("mivnadic");
                 }

              }

            // Write the content into xml file
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
            transformer.transform(source, result);

        }

        System.out.println("File saved");

       } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
       } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
       } catch (SAXException sae) {
        sae.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Elaborate "not working"

Comment: Nothing is happen when I run code. I want to change username with this "dummy" name .. Also now I'm trying to make writing trough document builder

Comment: Files in programming environments are overrated. One can read from `stdin`, write to `stdout` and the one can call the program with I/O redirection to read/write from/to files. For instance `java -jar program.jar < file.xml | sponge file.xml`

Comment: Furthermore is Java required anyway? This looks like a good job for an xslt processor.

Comment: Elaborate "Nothing is happen". Something MUST happen. What is printed in the console? What happens when you execute the code, line by line, in your debugger? Why are you trying to save an empty document? Why do you save the file *inside* the for loop, for each child node?

Comment: Hey, I solve problem, with diffrent aproach